# filter date/time-related columns based on other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am dealing with a database (db; schema: main) in pgAdmin4 with the following structure:

```
ID     date           time     
A      2016-10-02     16:52     
A      2016-10-03     19:23   
A      2016-10-04     12:47   
B      2012-07-14     18:39   
B      2012-07-16     22:48
B      2012-07-17     23:32
```

First, I want to get a new column with the date/time as timestamp (datetime), which I achieved with this code:

```
ALTER TABLE main.db ADD COLUMN datetime timestamp with time zone;

UPDATE main.db
SET datetime = CONCAT(date, ' ',time)::timestamp with time zone;
```

I would like to obtain the earliest and latest date/time per ID, so it should look something like:

```
ID     datetime           
A      2016-10-02 16:52       
B      2012-07-14 18:39
```

For the earliest record; and this for the latest record:

```
ID     datetime     
A      2016-10-04 12:47   
B      2012-07-17 23:32
```

1) Does anyone know how could I obtain this?

2) Additionally, I would like then to connect these results with columns from other tables (with ID in common). I have done that for tables already existing (using INNER JOIN), but never with a result of a query. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question completely, but isn't that a simple:

```
select id, min(datetime), max(datetime)
from the_table
group by id;
```

You can join that to other tables:

```
select ...
from (
  select id, min(datetime) as min_date, max(datetime) as max_date
  from the_table
  group by id
) as t1
  join other_table t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: This does work, thanks!! I tried at least the "max()" before (or similar, apparently), but it was not working.

Comment: and what should be in "..."?  (second query)